# hg mq (nested|sub|child) queues

Tags: version-control, mercurial, dvcs

I know this is not an hg feature, but maybe someone knows a way to get something similar. Hopefully my description makes sense:

I find it usefully to keep my mainline (i.e. default branch) commits in a patch queue for a few weeks to let them "settle". However, I'd also like to be able to create topic branches via new queues. These two ideas are mutually exclusive, as you cannot create new queues starting at an applied patch. Sounds like the only way to do this is to finalize my mainline patches, and start branch queues off the qparent commit, and handle tweaks by importing finalized patches back to mq. Any other ideas? Is git better at this sort of workflow?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ChangesetEvolution.

It's quite possible that this workflow is slightly easier in git.

Answer (score 0):

I will caveat this answer with "I have not tried it and have no idea if it'll work, or if it's what you want".

When you create a MQ for your repository, it creates it as a new Mercurial repo inside the current one, so your internal structure is something like this:

```
.hg\
  cache\
  patches\
    .hg\
    .hgignore
    patch1
    patch2
    series
    status
  store\
  hgrc
  ...
```

You can make operations directly on the patches repository (in fact if you're anything like me you'll have some kind of script set up to work easily on that repo - for me I have the `mq` command).

As the MQ is a repository in its own right, it can be committed-to, pulled, pushed, etc.  In theory this could include branching.

A possible workflow would be that, every time you think you're happy with a patch, you commit it to the patch repo:

```
hg qnew Patch3 -m "something"
...
hg qref
mq commit -m "happy with patch3"
```

Note that this isn't committing the patch to your main repository, it's simply storing the history of the patch.  If at some point you decided you wanted to create a branch, you could do it with:

```
mq branch SomeBranch
hg qnew Patch4 -m "something else"
...
hg qref
mq commit -m "Committing to the new patch branch"
mq update default
```

The `Patch4` patch is now branched off, and doesn't appear in your patch series, even in the unapplied list.

It's a possible solution that could work, but would need to be thoroughly tested on a test repository, and if you're not careful it could also go hideously wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`mq` has the `guard` functionality which could give you the flexibility you need, as described [in the hgbook](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/advanced-uses-of-mercurial-queues.html). Assuming you have three patches:

- `patch-a` - your mainline patch that you are letting "settle"
- `patch-b` - a new patch with incomplete work on feature1
- `patch-c` - a new patch beginning feature2

You only need to assign a guard where needed:

```
hg qpop -a
hg qguard patch-b +feature1
hg qguard patch-c +feature2
hg qselect feature2
hg qpush -a
```

At this point, `mq` will push all unguarded (`patch-a`) and the positively guarded (`patch-c`) patches, skipping `patch-b` since it has a guard that is not currently selected. Unguarded patches are always applied. There are also negative guards (e.g. `hg qguard -- -feature1`) which prevent the application of the patch when the guard is selected.

To switch over to feature1:

```
hg qpop -a
hg qselect feature1
hg qpush -a
```

Note that if you are doing this much work in the patch queue, you should commit the queue itself quite often to track your changes on the queue (using `hg com --mq`).